# doenst work Autowired

Tags: spring, spring-boot

my `@Autowired (socket_mesajService)` doenst work in the  `SocketHandler.class`  I got a `NullPointerException`  but `@Autowired (socket_mesajService)` is working for other classes.

this is my SocketHandler class and call to socket_mesajService in this class

```
@Component
public class SocketHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {
    @Autowired
    private Socket_mesajService socket_mesajService;

    List<Socket_session_model> sessions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        for(Socket_session_model socket_session__model : sessions) {
            socket_mesajService.Socket_mesaj_templateAll(socket_session__model.getUserid());
        }
    }
}
```

this is my WebSocketConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/name");

 }
```

this is my ApplicationRun class //////////////////////

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication   (scanBasePackages={"com.polipool.*"})
@EntityScan( basePackages = {"com.polipool.model"})
public class ApplicationRun extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRun.class, args);
    }

  @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
    }

  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
  builder) {
      return builder.sources(ApplicationRun.class);
   }

}
```

Socket_mesajServiceImpl class

```
@Service
public class Socket_mesajServiceImpl implements Socket_mesajService {
@Autowired
private Socket_mesajDao socket_mesajDao;
@Override
public List<Socket_mesaj_template> Socket_mesaj_templateAll(String 
messageid) {
    return socket_mesajDao.Socket_mesaj_templateAll(messageid);
}

}
```

Socket_mesajService

```
public interface Socket_mesajService {
public void Socket_mesaj_tamplateadd (Socket_mesaj_template mesaj);
public void Socket_mesaj_templateupdate (Socket_mesaj_template user);
public void Socket_mesaj_templatedelete (String messageid);
public List<Socket_mesaj_template> Socket_mesaj_templateAll (String userid);
}
```

Comment: Where do you declare `Socket_mesajService` bean?

Comment: List<Socket_session_model> sessions = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    public void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message)
            throws InterruptedException, IOException {
            
            for(Socket_session_model socket_session__model : sessions) {
            
            socket_mesajService.Socket_mesaj_templateAll(socket_session__model.getUserid())
            }
  
        }

Comment: no no dude, edit your question with this class added

Comment: i add look at up pls

Comment: I don't see your `Socket_mesajService` class

Comment: soryy, i add now

Comment: Add the package for the `Socket_mesajService` as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem lies on this line:

```
registry.addHandler(new SocketHandler(), "/name");
```

You creat an instance of `SocketHandler` yourself so your properties inside it will be `null`

Instead, `@Autowired` the `SocketHandler` to your `WebSocketConfig` config class, and add that instance to "`registry`" will solve your problem